# Breaking down elements of an array into an independent array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a matrix:
`A{i}=[Element1 ELement2 Element3 Element4]`.
It is a 1X4 cell array.

Each element of matrix A is an array in itself with size n x n.

I was wondering if I can break down A{i} into 4 independent arrays?

The condition is that the code is part of a function, therefore I cannot manually punch in `X=ans(:,1) .........ans(:,4)` in the command window. Even though it works.

If there is a way to do that within a function, please let me know.

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to do. I guess  you want something like this: `[w,x,y,z]=A{:};`

Comment: Well I am trying to compute a matrix which is multiplication the elements of A{i} in order element1 * element2 * element3 * element4

Comment: If they are for example of size [m x n] how do you want to multiply those matrices? They have incompatible sizes.

Comment: Thank You for catching the mistake ( I edited the question). They are all square matrices [n x n].

Comment: Can't you use a for loop?

Comment: That is exactly what I have been trying to do, but, how can I assign four different variables one element of A{i}?

Comment: You don't need to create variables you can do this: `result =A{1};for k = 2: numel(A);result = result * A{k};end`

Comment: Thank You, it worked. But I am still wondering, if there is a way to break a matrix elements into independent matrices?

Comment: MATLAB provide you array and cell array  for such use cases. Creating variables on the fly,though is possible, isn't a good programming style.